# Why is my logo not showing?

Tags: html, css, image, class

Why is my logo not showing on my site? In my header.php there is this code `<div class="logo"><a href="index.php"></a></div>` which has a class and a link to a page so when people click the logo they go to the home page.

Style:

```
.logo {
    float:left;
    width:228px;
    height:50px;
    margin:30px 0 0 12px;
}
.logo a {
    display:block;
    width:228px;
    height:50px;
    background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

The logo is in the right folder and I know in fact it should be showing, but still doesn't. Does any one know what the problem might be?

Tested it on a normal HTML file and it's working there, but in my header.php it doesn't.

Comment: The path is probably wrong. Use an absolute path.

Comment: Can you show your header file.

Comment: Note that the image file path is relative to the `.css` file location

Comment: Well we would need more information. Could you give us a working example of what is going on to see the issue more clearly. Use the inspect element feature in modern browsers to see if the image is actually being loaded and the path is correct. Also is there a reason you do not want to use <img>?

Answer (score -1):

The image won't show if you don't write something inside the  tag. Try doing this:

```
<a href="index.php">My site</a>
```

And then add this property to your .logo a css to hide the text:

```
text-indent:-9999px;
```

Then your image should appear.

Answer (score -2):

because in your CSS you are using background image:

```
background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat left top;
```

In this case, if there is nothing written in your div, the background will not be shown, which means you can't see your logo.

If you try to show your image no matter what's in the div, you should refer to your image directly, not as a background of a div.

Comment: There is something in the div, an a tag. But OP also sets width and height.